# Component returned failure code: 0x805e0006 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

The following JQuery `get` call:

```
var doc_root = document.location.hostname + ":8082";
var fw_script = doc_root + "/sites/MyScripts/fw2.php";
var langpref = "EN";

var ttype = "BEGIN";
var vvalue = $("#inp_begin").val();

$.get(fw_script, { type: ttype, value: vvalue, langpref: langpref })
    .success(function(result) {
        $(fw_result).text(result);
        alert("Success");
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(fw_result).text("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        alert("Failure");
    });
```

is generating the following error message (`.error` is called):

```
Error: error [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x805e0006
[nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]" nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)" location: "JS frame ::
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
:: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4" data: no]
```

I have no idea what this message is and I can't find much explanation with my Googling. Can anyone clarify?

**UPDATE**

The called URL is constructed as following in Javascript:

```
var doc_root = document.location.hostname + ":8082";
var fw_script = doc_root + "/sites/MyScripts/fw2.php";
```

and `fw_script`'s value is:

```
fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyScripts/fw2.php
```

It is called from

```
fw.localhost:8082/en
```

When I try `fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyScripts/fw2.php` in my browser, it is successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks very likely that you're dealing with a cross-domain request error. According to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't make an AJAX request to a host with a different port number, even if it's the same domain. It looks like you're setting `doc_root` to a different origin, by this definition, so you'll likely get an error on the AJAX request.

The standard options for fixing this:

- Serve your data from the same host you're making the request from.
- Use JSONP instead of JSON.

Comment: I checked the called URL, but the port seems OK (if I did not miss anything). I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: A quick Google seems to indicate that the AdBlock FF extension is sometimes the source of this error. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Your initial suggestion was right, and I had not refreshed my system properly when testing your suggestion. My bad. Problem solved.

Comment: Just to note I had the same error in FF (Chrome worked fine) and it was caused by the AdBlock extension.

Comment: Was an Ad Blocker issue for me. Is there any way I can get the 4 hours added back onto my lifespan?

Answer (score 1):

Just to call attention to the sleuthing done by @nrabinowitz and other commenters: **check your ad blocker/privacy plugin**. In my case, Privacy Badger started blocking `localhost`.