# Error 0x805e0006 when submitting form over SSL (Exception... "<no message>")

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ssl

So I am working on my WordPress website www.artemisbrandwax.com and when trying to submit a form when https:// (SSL) is loaded it refreshes the page and won't submit. The error is:

```
Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame ::
https://artemisbrandwax.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0 :: .send ::
line 4"  data: no]
```

And here's an image:

[image]

Here is the link and credentials: https://www.artemisbrandwax.com/profile, Username: *tester*, Password: *thepassword*.

Any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: open your `wp-config.php` file and do this: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, then do that agian.

Comment: Perhaps [Component returned failure code: 0x805e0006 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792153/jquery-component-returned-failure-code-0x805e0006-error) would be helpful?

Comment: This also looks really similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304429/ajax-request-not-sent-error-unknown-in-firefox

Comment: Left info there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394496/2494754